# How to select div in table cell using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell, selector

I have the following table structure:

```
            <tr>
                <th><label for="ctl00_bodyContent_username">username:</label></th>
                <td class="field"><input name="ctl00$bodyContent$username" type="text" id="ctl00_bodyContent_username" /></td>
                <td class="info">
                    <div class="message">what do you want to be known as?</div>
                    <div class="valid">username available</div>
                    <div class="invalid">this username is already taken</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

What I'm looking to achieve is when the textbox #ctl00_bodyContent_username has focus, te div .message is shown (default is display:none) in the adjacent table cell.

Comment: +1 for the question and for good, accessible HTML!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are more than one of these (and not just one as the other are assuming):

```
$("td.field :input").focus(function() {
  var info = $(this).parent().next();
  if ($(".valid:visible, .invalid:visible", info).length == 0) {
    info.children("message").show();
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var info = $(this).parent().next();
  info.children("message").hide();
});
```

This also assumes you want to hide the message when the field loses focus.

Comment: That thought crossed my mind too, but then judging by the content, it looks as though the *table* is a user registration form

Comment: @Russ http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ uses an entry form that has a message on each row.  I'm with cletus that he's looking for something like this.

Comment: @cletus you should chain the focus and blur calls so they don't load the selector twice.

Comment: True. Done. Not really for performance reasons though. Avoiding possible typos is reason enough.

Comment: Is it possible to make this conditional? You'll notice there are two other div's there, valid and invalid. I only want to show the message div if the valid and invalid aren't visible.

Comment: Amended to add a condition (if I understand your intent correctly).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ctl00_bodyContent_username").focus(function(){
  $(".message").show();
})
```

Let me give you a brief information about **Show()** method :

Same as show( speed, [callback] ) without animations. Doesn't change anything if the selected elements are all visible. **It doesn't matter if the element is hidden via a hide() call, or via a display:none in a stylesheet.**

From : [JQuery Effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show)

Comment: -1 Unfortunately this wont work if you have more than 1 row.  It will show messages on all row.

Comment: Well, it will work unless you don't add more than one row which have same names and that is what this guy is asking about :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry guys. Should've realised that only posting one row would cause problems. I have about 5/6 of these rows with the same classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#ctl00_bodyContent_username").focus(function(){
  $(this).parent().next().children('.message').show();
})
```

where

**parent**

Get the direct parent of an element. If called on a set of elements, parent returns a set of their unique direct parent elements.

**next**

Get a set of elements containing the unique next siblings of each of the given set of elements.

**children**

Get a set of elements containing all of the unique immediate children of each of the matched set of elements.

**show**

Displays each of the set of matched elements if they are hidden.

See [traversing](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) in jQuery docs for more information.